# Matrix-valued function that implies an upper bound

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

In the following $\mathbf R^{2\times 2}$ denotes the linear space of real $2\times 2$- matrices and $\|\cdot \|$ denotes an arbitrary norm in $\mathbf R^2$. Further $\langle R(x), y\rangle$ stands for the evaluation of $R(x)$ at $y$ (matrix-vector-product).

> $\textbf{1.}$ Let $C=\mathbf R^2$. Is it possible to find a matrix-valued function $R:\mathbf R^2 \to \mathbf R^{2\times 2}$ such that for all $x,y\in C$ with
>   $$\langle R(x),y\rangle - \langle R(x),x\rangle \notin - \operatorname{int} \mathbf R_+^2,$$
>   there exists a positive constant $L$ (only depending on $y$) such that $\|x\| \leq L \|y\|$?
>
> $\textbf{2.}$ What further assumptions on $R$ do we need to get that relation in the first question?
>
> $\textbf{3.}$ Can we replay $C$ in question 1 by another unbounded set such that the implication holds?

Comment: $\langle R(x),y\rangle - \langle R(x),x\rangle$ is a real number but what is $ - \operatorname{int} \mathbf R_+^2$?

Comment: Sorry, for the confusion. Of course, $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle $ does not denote the dot product. Here $\langle R(x),y\rangle$ stands for the evalutation of $R(x)$ at $y$, in other words, $\langle R(x),y\rangle= R(x)*y$, where $*$ is the matrix product. $-\operatorname{int} \mathbf R_+^2 = \{ (x_1,x_2) \in \mathbf R^2 \mid x_1 < 0 \text{ and } x_2<0 \}$.

Comment: So you want to say the following?: $\forall y \exists L > 0 : R(x)(y-x)\not\in Q_4 \implies \|x\|\le L\|y\|$

(where $Q_4$ is the 4th quadrant). In this case a trivial solution would be given by $R=0$.

Comment: Yes. $R=0$ is not that interesting. Of course I am looking for nontrivial solutions. Btw. thank you very much for thinking about my problem here! :)

Comment: $R=0$ is not a solution. Since for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^2$, $R(x)(x-y)=(0,0)\not\in Q_3$ and for a fixed $y$ the number $L||y||$ will never be a bound of $\{||x||:x\in\mathbb{R}^2\}$.

Comment: Oh yes, you are absolutely right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to put more restrictions on the precise properties.
Otherwise there is a very simple solution with $L=1$ (unless I misunderstood something):

Let $e= (1,1)\in{\rm int}\; {\Bbb R}_+^2 $ and define $R(x)u = e (x^T u)$

Then $R(x)(y-x) \notin -{\rm int} \;{\Bbb R}_+^2 $ iff $x^T (y-x)\geq 0$ which in turn implies $|x|\leq |y|$.

Q2. Since Q1 was possible I suppose this becomes obsolete?

Q3: It obviously works in any dimension.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I thought of so many little examples and did not find this easy one!

Comment: Enjoy your bounty!

Comment: OK, thanks. Glad that it really was what you needed.